# How to put google credentials into shiny web app without login

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny, credentials, public

I have created my google authentification and got this:

googleAuthR.webapp.client_id
googleAuthR.webapp.client_secret

I want to put these credentials into my shiny web app,
with the goal that my shiny app can read and write from a (public) spreadsheet
without doing this before:

The googlesheets4 package is requesting access to your Google account
Select a pre-authorised account or enter '0' to obtain a new token
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to cancel

I want do deploy my shiny web app on the R server, but it failed because of missing credentials

Warnung: Error in : Can't get Google credentials. (from Log file)

How can I make it possible?
I found some solutions with login, but everyone should use these dashboard without logging in

I created OAuth 2.0 Client IDs

And tryed these code:

```
gs4_auth(
  email = "my@gmail.com",
  path = jsonsecret,
  scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
  cache = gargle::gargle_oauth_cache(),
  use_oob = gargle::gargle_oob_default(),
  token = ".secret"
)
```

Comment: What type of credentials are you using? How did you integrate them in your web app? Can you provide more details? Also, what scopes are you using?

Comment: I updated my question, I tryed mostly everything but r says:
 Fehler in value[[3L]](cond) : Can't get Google credentials. 

And locally it doesnt work without login too